# Using multiprocessing with AllenNLP decoding is sluggish compared to non-multiprocessing case

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing, allennlp

I'm using the AllenNLP (version 2.6) semantic role labeling model to process a large pile of sentences. My Python version is 3.7.9. I'm on MacOS 11.6.1. My goal is to use `multiprocessing.Pool` to parallelize the work, but the calls via the pool are taking longer than they do in the parent process, sometimes substantially so.

In the parent process, I have explicitly placed the model in shared memory as follows:

```
from allennlp.predictors import Predictor            
from allennlp.models.archival import load_archive
import allennlp_models.structured_prediction.predictors.srl
PREDICTOR_PATH = "...<srl model path>..."

archive = load_archive(PREDICTOR_PATH)
archive.model.share_memory()
PREDICTOR = Predictor.from_archive(archive)
```

I know the model is only being loaded once, in the parent process. And I place the model in shared memory whether or not I'm going to make use of the pool. I'm using `torch.multiprocessing`, as many recommend, and I'm using the `spawn` start method.

I'm calling the predictor in the pool using `Pool.apply_async`, and I'm timing the calls within the child processes. I know that the pool is using the available CPUs (I have six cores), and I'm nowhere near running out of physical memory, so there's no reason for the child processes to be swapped to disk.

Here's what happens, for a batch of 395 sentences:

- Without multiprocessing: 638 total processing seconds (and elapsed time).
- With a 4-process pool: 293 seconds elapsed time, 915 total processing seconds.
- With a 12-process pool: 263 seconds elapsed time, 2024 total processing seconds.

The more processes, the worse the total AllenNLP processing time - even though the model is explicitly in shared memory, and the only thing that crosses the process boundary during the invocation is the input text and the output JSON.

I've done some profiling, and the first thing that leaps out at me is that the function `torch._C._nn.linear` is taking significantly longer in the multiprocessing cases. This function takes two tensors as arguments - but there are no tensors being passed across the process boundary, and I'm decoding, not training, so the model should be entirely read-only. It seems like it has to be a problem with locking or competition for the shared model resource, but I don't understand at all why that would be the case. And I'm not a `torch` programmer, so my understanding of what's happening is limited.

Any pointers or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I also tried copying the model in the predictor as part of the initialization code for the pool element, using ```copy.deepcopy```, but that just made it take longer to create the pool element, and didn't noticeably reduce the AllenNLP processing time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I wasn't comparing exactly the right things. This thread: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/discussions/5471 goes into all the detail. Briefly, because `pytorch` can use additional resources under the hood, my baseline test without multiprocessing wasn't taxing my computer enough when running two instances in parallel; I had to run 4 instances to see the penalty, and in that case, the total processing time was essentially the same for 4 parallel nonmultiprocessing invocations, or one multiprocessing case with 4 subprocesses.